# use greater<char>() in priority_queue

Tags: c++, function, std

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <queue>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<char> a(256);
    copy(istream_iterator<char>{ cin }, istream_iterator<char>{}, begin(a));
    priority_queue<char> q{ less<char> (),a }; // less -> greater = compile error
    while (!q.empty()) {
        cout << q.top();
        q.pop();
    }

}
```

I'm trying to practice priority_queue. and I can't use `greater<char>()` intead of `less` Why I can't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, given `priority_queue<char> q ...`, the compare type would be the [default template argument](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue), i.e. `std::less<char>`, which doesn't match if you pass `greater<char>` as constructor argument.

You can specify all the template arguments explicitly as

```
priority_queue<char, vector<char>, greater<char>> q{ greater<char> (),a };
```

Or don't specify any template arguments to take advantage of [class template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) (since C++17).

```
priority_queue q{ greater<char> (),a };
```